# BPF Filtered lookup field not working in certain stages

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

In my case same lookup field in BPF for two more stages in a process which is working in stage1 and not working in stage2 and stage3.

```
 function Filter(executionContext) {
    debugger;
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    var control = Xrm.Page.getControl("header_process_attributename");
    if (control) {       
        formContext.getControl("header_process_new_attributename").setDefaultView("{**View Guid**}");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working by using following code:

Need to change attribute name as follows

Stage 2:

```
var control = Xrm.Page.getControl("header_process_attributename_1");
```

Stage 3:

```
var control = Xrm.Page.getControl("header_process_attributename_2");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
formcontext.getattributes().controls.forEach(function (control) {
    if (control && control.addCustomView) {
        var viewId = "{65FFAF9A-E8C5-432D-860B-32F841B00D87}"; //All Accounts
        var entityName = 'account';
        var viewDisplayName = 'ShipTo Accounts';
        control.addCustomView(viewId, entityName, viewDisplayName, fetchXml, layoutXml, true);
    }
});
```

There can be 2 issues here

1. When we wish to work with same lookup field perhaps name of that lookup field on next stage is `header_process_attributename2`
2. It can also happen that you do not get control of that field because of load issue.

In this case I would suggest you take all the controls on form and then iterate over them to get correct controls.

Code snippet above

Comment: Ank thanks for your answer! i wish to work with same lookup field with same schema name on 2 more stages. in this case its working in stage1 and not working in stage2 ,stage 3